# Intermittent "Err_Connection_Refusued" error on a WordPress website

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, ssl, wordpress

I have been troubleshooting an intermittent issue with users accessing a locally hosted WordPress website and getting `Err_Connection_Refused`.

[image: Err_Connection_Refused_Screenshot]

This issue has been very intermittent. There seems to be no pattern of which users it's happening to or when. Typically switching browser's "resolves" the issue i.e if they're in Chrome and try opening it in Edge and vise versa it will successfully load the page. In addition, a user will have trouble accessing it while their co-worker right next to them is able to access it on their computer without trouble.

It is a simple WordPress site which mostly contains small company updates and links to common company resources. It is running on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS an ESXi host with a 10GB fiber card. It is only accessible via the local LAN. We have a DNS pointer on our AD server pointing to its local static IP. It is accessed via HTTPS (Default Port 443) and has an SSL certificate.

Troubleshooting Steps / Research already taken:

- Monitored Resource Usage via htop (confirmed resource usage was fine while a user was actively having the issue)
- Added more RAM to the ESXi host (just in case)
- Verified port was open on firewall
- I used nslookup and verified DNS was resolving correctly to the right IP.
- Reviewed Site-Avalible config and verified the SSL settings look correct.
- Added monitor tool to check access every 10 seconds (So far is has not provided helpful data as it does not appear to go down even when a user is reporting the issue.)
- I changed the http to https redirect config under apache sites-available config to use "permanent"
- Verified network connectivity seems to be stable (no packet loss & 1 ms. latency)
- Tried changing local IP and updated DNS pointer (no difference)
  Also the obvious, rebooted the server, even setup a cronjob to restart the apache service nightly.
- I scoured the internet and stackoverflow for any solutions, but typically I just found the basic things that I've already checked.

Comment: This error most often indicates a client-side problem. Possibilities are endless: Faulty internet connection, synchronization error, bad browser extensions, antivirus, firewall, VPN interference, outdated browser or DNS cache. You need to reduce the number of possibilities.

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.  ALL questions about Wordpress are out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: @Ramhound this is mostly about networking, not really the WP site.

Comment: @music2myear - I am not entirely convinced the issue isn't the WordPress configuration or perhaps Apache configuration.

Comment: WordPress won't be the thing refusing the connection. Yes, it may be off topic, but it isn't so because or WP.